# Terraform - create output from module with splat operator not working

Tags: terraform

I have defined a module with a loop:

```
module "stamp" {
  for_each = toset(var.stamps)
  source   = "./modules/stamp"
  ...
}
```

From this I am trying to create an output list, based on [this example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/output.html#examples):

```
output "stamp_locations" {
  value = module.stamp.*.location
}
```

However, this validates but on `terraform plan` I get the error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on output.tf line 3, in output "stamp_locations":
│    3:   value = module.stamp.*.location
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "location"
```

Only this worked in the end:

```
output "stamp_locations" {
  value = [for instance in module.stamp : instance.location]
}
```

So I am wondering: Did I make any mistake or is the splat-syntax not supported with modules and loops?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`module.stamp` is a map, not a list. The following should work with your map:

```
value = values(module.stamp)[*].location
```

`values` will return a list of values from your `module.stamp`.